# Navigating to each item in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a list of products and need to navigate to each product from that list and show data passed from HomeScreen do DetailsScreen.I'm trying to navigate between screens using react-navigation.

I pass bellow JSON data as a state when I navigate to DetailsScreen.
Can't find the right solution to navigate to a clicked product.

How can I pass just one item of the array to next screen so when you open DetailsScreen you always have right data?
Or can I somehow navigate with an index to exactly details screen?

I have some JSON data :

```
{ "products" : [{
    "id": "0",
    "imageUrl":
      "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_1728_v1/f_auto/bfbtp31oaoe1haptpdcz/free-tr-flyknit-3-training-shoe-rJTGVbmL.jpg",
    "title": "Nike Free TR Flyknit 3",
    "price": "60$",
    "userPhone": "041-425-900",
    "userEmail": "adam@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "imageUrl":
      "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_864_v1/f_auto/dhw4wxp9ebyef1q35f4g/metcon-4-cross-training-weightlifting-shoe-1qTbMObn.jpg",
    "title": "Nike Metcon 4",
    "price": "127$",
    "userPhone": "041-125-400",
    "userEmail": "davids@gmail.com"
  },

  {
    "id": "2",
    "imageUrl":
      "https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_1728_v1/f_auto/xzei8hswzsvdv1xlsd5e/air-max-90-leather-shoe-xqTPGEVE.jpg",
    "title": "Nike Air Max 90 Leather",
    "price": "200$",
    "userPhone": "041-211-320",
    "userEmail": "ragnar@gmail.com"
    }]
  }
```

HomeScreen:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: data.products,
    };
  }


  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  //Bellow is navigation method and passing JSON as state
  openDetails = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
      data: this.state.data,
    });
  };


  renderProduct = ({ item, index }) => {
    console.log('index je', this.state.index);
    return (
      <Item
        itemTitle={item.title}
        openDetails={this.openDetails}
        itemUrl={item.imageUrl}
        data={this.state.data}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderProduct}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

DetailsScreen:

```
    class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

    const data = params ? params.data : null;        

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text>{JSON.stringify(data.title)}</Text>
  </View>
);
  }
}

export default withNavigation(DetailsScreen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is being passed as the navigation and the components are connected, and your **Item Component** is your **DetailsScreen** therefore you can do the following

```
openDetails = (data) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", { 
      data  <== // ... pass the item data here
    });
  };

      <Item
        itemTitle={item.title}
        openDetails={() => this.openDetails(item)} // Get the item data by referencing as a new function to it
        itemUrl={item.imageUrl}
        data={this.state.data}
      />
```

**DetailsScreen.js**

Wrap your view in `TouchableOpacity` to access `Touchable` events

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.openDetails} style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}> //... Bind the openDetails function to the prop here
   <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props.itemTitle)}</Text> //...<== Access the other props here
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I was upon this solution when you posted that. Thanks a lot!